# Can I use s3fs cache for Nginx?

Tags: caching, nginx, ownership, s3fs, file-ownership

I’m using s3fs for Web contents storage. Its mount point is `/data/example.com/`. The s3fs cache path is `/data/cache/example.com/`.

My Nginx currently uses `/data/example.com/` for the document root. I want to change this to `/data/cache/example.com`, but Nginx says “Permission denied”.

I used the following s3fs options for mount ownership in `/etc/fstab`:

```
s3fs#example.com /data/example.com fuse nosuid,nodev,allow_other,uid=500,gid=500,umask=022,use_cache=/data/cache 0 0
```

How can I set ownership of the s3fs cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should never do. The s3fs cache filesystem is internal stuff, which is not meant to be used by any external applications. They can change the format of cache files at any time; they could modify cached files for any reason and you will get corrupted data.

Why do you want to use a cache filesystem instead of the mounted filesystem located at `/data/example.com`?